How to bypass system volume on audio player?
How can I ignore the system volume so that when an MP3 is played and, for example, the iPhone's volume is set to 5%, the AudioPlayer's volume is always at 100%?
Currently, the Audio Player adjusts to the iPhone's media volume!
func playProgressTone() {
    guard let soundURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "ProgressTone", withExtension: "mp3") else {
        print("Error: Audio file 'ProgressTone.mp3' not found.")
        return
    }

    do {
        progressTonePlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL)
        progressTonePlayer?.volume = 5.0
        progressTonePlayer?.numberOfLoops = -1 // Repeat until the call is connected

        // Delay of 1.0 seconds before playing the sound
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) { [weak progressTonePlayer] in
            progressTonePlayer?.play()
            print("Progress tone will play after 1 second.")
        }

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error playing the progress tone: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}


"the Audio Player adjusts to the iPhone's media volume". I would hope so. Why do you think you should be able to override the user's volume setting?

Hi,
One possibility is with the MediaPlayer framework.
First you create an Extension for the MPVolumeView so that you can control the volume more easily.
Volume is always passed as a Float.
Reason: DRY = Don't Repeat Yourself
1. MPVolumeView Extension:
extension MPVolumeView {
    static func setVolume(_ volume: Float) {
        let volumeView = MPVolumeView()
        let slider = volumeView.subviews.first(where: { $0 is UISlider }) as? UISlider
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
            slider?.value = volume
        }
    }
}

2. Functions
To make it easier, I have created 2 functions, you could integrate it into your function, for example.

useCustomVolume(): with this we save the current system volume in a state var (state variable) and then set the system Volume to 100%.

func useCustomVolume() {
    systemVolume = Float(AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().outputVolume)
    MPVolumeView.setVolume(Float(1.0))
}


useSystemVolume(): here we now take the saved volume from the State Variable and restore it.

func useSystemVolume() {
    MPVolumeView.setVolume(systemVolume)
}

3. TL;DR Here is an example, using a View:
import SwiftUI
import MediaPlayer

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var systemVolume: Float = 0.0
    @State private var usesCustomVolume: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Text("systemVolume: \(systemVolume)")
            
            
            Button {
                useCustomVolume()
            } label: {
                Text("100% Volume")
            }
            
            
            Button {
                useSystemVolume()
            } label: {
                Text("System Volume")
            }
            
        }
        
        
    }
    
    func useCustomVolume() {
        systemVolume = Float(AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().outputVolume)
        MPVolumeView.setVolume(Float(1.0))
    }
    
    func useSystemVolume() {
        MPVolumeView.setVolume(systemVolume)
    }
    
}

4. Finally:
You should always bear in mind that it could disturb a user in a productive version of your app, as the volume setting is usually made deliberately.
5. Usefull Documentation:
MPVolumeView (Apple Documentation)
MediaPlayer (Apple Documentation)
